# C# How to upload large file to ftp ( File size must 500 MB - 1 GB)

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie, I want to send a large file to ftp using C# but I can't send files above 500 MB - 1 GB. Could someone please help me? Thank you.

The code I'm using is:

```
    private void btnUpload_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        NetworkStream passiveConnection;
        FileInfo fileParse = new FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName);
        FileStream fs = new
        FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        byte[] fileData = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(fileData, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        passiveConnection = createPassiveConnection();
        string cmd = "STOR " + fileParse.Name + "\r\n";
        tbStatus.Text += "\r\nSent:" + cmd;
        string response = sendFTPcmd(cmd);
        tbStatus.Text += "\r\nRcvd:" + response;
        passiveConnection.Write(fileData, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        passiveConnection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Uploaded");
        tbStatus.Text += "\r\nRcvd:" + new
        StreamReader(NetStrm).ReadLine(); getRemoteFolders();
    }
```

Comment: What does "can't send" mean?

Comment: Is there a specif reason you don't use [System.Net.FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) and its FtpWebResponse counterpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not read the whole file (it will consume too much memory and time), read by blocks:

```
NetworkStream passiveConnection;
FileInfo fileParse = new FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName);
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open))
{
     byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
     int read;

     passiveConnection = createPassiveConnection();
     string cmd = "STOR " + fileParse.Name + "\r\n";
     tbStatus.Text += "\r\nSent:" + cmd;
     string response = sendFTPcmd(cmd);
     tbStatus.Text += "\r\nRcvd:" + response;

     while ((read = fs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length) > 0)
     {
         passiveConnection.Write(buf, 0, read);
     }
}

passiveConnection.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Uploaded");
tbStatus.Text += "\r\nRcvd:" + new
StreamReader(NetStrm).ReadLine(); 
getRemoteFolders();
```

And yes, what about [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: just use `fs.CopyTo(passiveConnection)`.

Comment: @user3093720 :) You are welcome, sir :). If it helped you, please mark as the answer. Cory's comment is useful too.

Answer (score -2):

I think you will need also dlls to make transfer easier.
Also Asynchronous socket would prevent such fail errors during transfer.

Comment: what kind of dlls ?

Comment: Not clear answer nor related to the question.